# Entity Framework 6 Code First Migrations using Identity user models in a separate project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

Is it possible using EF6 Code First and MVC5 to put all the models, views, and controllers that involve ASP.Identity into its own class library project. So that over multiple web applications you could use that same DLL and already have all the views / controllers / models and be using the same security database for multiple applications?

We have several web applications with separate databases and one security database that handles all of them, and we weren't sure how to keep this model now that we're moving to EF6 Code First and MVC5.

If it is possible could someone point me to a tutorial of something similar or give me a basic outline of steps to go through?

Or if there is a better way to achieve my goal, of having one set of code to handle ASP.NET-Identity security that I can plug that dll into multiple web applications and get the same logic and databases?

Or is this not a good idea in general?

Very open to suggestion and advice. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. We do this with every project that we have. The structure is very simple. Just create a class library project to your solution, add EF to the project, then reference the class library from your main project.

If using Code First Migrations be sure to select the class library project as the default project in the Package Manager console when running migrations or adding migrations.

Here is a pseudo solution structure for your solution

```
MySolution
  - MyWebApp
     reference: MyDAL
  -MyDAL
     reference: EF6
```

The advantage that I find to this is that you can then reference the "DAL" class library from say a companion console application or windows form application, or a companion website, even in a different solution, and they will use the same code base.

For example:

```
MySolution
  - MyWebApp
     reference: MyDAL
  - MyDAL
     reference: EF6
  - MyOtherWebApp
     reference: MyDAL
```

**NOTE:** Your data context will look for its connection string in the Web.config or App.config in the *startup* project. ***NOT*** the class library. This can be confusing at first... But once you think about how .NET compiles the application together into the final package, it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. The two largest problems I was having was with the migrations and where to put the connection string for the security database.

Before I went into more detail I wanted to make sure what I was doing was best practice since I'm new to EF and ASP.Identity.

You helped me figure out the migration issue, on the connection string issue, would you keep it in the web.config of MyWebApp and set the connection in MyDAL when you reference it?

I was going to do that, but that would mean I'd need to include the security database connection in every web apps config.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: One other thing to note is that EF will use the web.config or the app.config in the **startup** project for the connection string. **NOT** the app.config in the class library.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about creating one class library for an entire data layer shared between multiple projects, then that's easy enough. You can move all your models, your context, etc. into a class library and run migrations using the class library project. The other projects will just reference that class library and not have migrations of their own.

However, if you're talking about multiple databases and associated data layers, where project Foo has its own models, context and migrations and project Bar has its own models, context and migrations, while the class library has just the `IdentityUser` and `IdentityDbContext`, things get a little more complicated. You won't be able to combine any of these contexts. So in your Foo project you'd have to instantiate your context for Foo *and* your Identity context if you need to work with both. It's not a problem, per se, but it's something to be aware of.